# Low Profile PCIe card in a standard ATX case - will it fit, and do I need adapters?

Tags: motherboard, pci-express, case, wireless-adapter, atx

I've got a standard normal-sized ATX case (don't know its name or specifications, because I got it from a friend) and a standard motherboard (MSI B150 PC-Mate) inside.

Since it doesn't come with a WLAN card, which I need, I was planning on using it with a PCIe WLAN adapter, which has a low profile bracket:

[image]

Now if I look into my case, it looks like there will be a gap on the backside where the card is gonna be, since it is obviously shorter than the other components and the case. I was wondering if there are good ways to circumvent this, as it seems to me like it could decrease the card's stability inside the case.

[image]

I found the above picture on wikipedia, which looks exactly like what I need - but even extensive googl'ing for things such as "low profile pci bracket" etc. didn't yield results.

I guess my question is: do I really need an extension/adapter bracket, or is there another way to properly install the card? And if not, what is that extension thing called, so I can at least know what to shop for.

Thanks for tips, or recommendations :)

Comment: Have you purchased the WLAN adapter yet? There is a chance it comes with a replaceable backplate and a full-height one is included.

Comment: As the previous commenter said, you should purchase the card for what you need... most LP cards come with a standard height and LP bracket for mounting, read the contents on the side of the box. TBH, if you find that adapter (I couldn't) it will likely cost more than a cheap PCI-E Wireless adapter, which can be purchased under $15 from a reputable retailer.

Comment: Thanks @acejavelin and Andrew. I will then just purchase it and see if it comes with a backplate. Either way, you are probably right about the cost, I hadn't figured that in ;)

Comment: @Aprillomat- what's pictured there isn't going to work because that bulge where the 2 pieces screw together isn't going to fit through the hole in the back of your case. It might work if you took off the half-height bracket & filipped it around, so the bulge points back *into* the case.  Removing the half-height bracket is easy, just unscrew those nuts above & below the DVI socket. For the wireless card, there is probably a screw behind the bracket & on the PCB. It looks symmetric, but then it also LL there's a flange on the bracket that could cause problems going through the back of the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was jus surfing [Amazon.com](https://goo.gl/y2Gs9J) and found your exact same card (same picture).  According to the listing, it comes with **both** half height and full height brackets.

[image]

If this is in fact your card, I am sure you could find the full height bracket on eBay if you already own the adapter.  I have found many half height quad Ethernet brackets on eBay for very little money.  However, I would **never** create a hack like one pictured.

Comment: yes, this is indeed the same card. the site where I found it on didn't say it came with both brackets, it only said Low Profile in the description text. But I guess this sorts that, so thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't mess with the plate (see my comment). It's going to be very hard to find something that fits that device. If you're really stuck on that particular card, there are all kinds of PCIe adapters or extenders on eBay. Since you'll be screwing the bracket in on the top, it should be okay to not have it seated on the bottom.

Here's [one example](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Sintech-PCI-e-express-16X-Riser-Extender-Card-5cm-high-speed-Flexible-Cable-/221770562888?hash=item33a28e3d48:g:5SUAAOSwBLlVUYAN):

[image]

Here's [another](http://www.ebay.com/itm/PCI-E-1X-Slot-Riser-Card-Extender-Extension-Ribbon-Flex-Cable-PCI-Express-Lead-/182161890986?hash=item2a69b1deaa:g:Pt8AAOSwMNxXVjQY):

[image]

Comment: Hadn't thought on that. Since it seems that the Wireless Adapter of my choice does indeed come with a full-lenth replacement bracket (see Allan's answer), I am luckily freed from that purchase. I appreciate your solution, though :)